# variable for image id

Tags: javascript, random, image, identifier

I have these   :

```
<th  scope="col"> 
        <img style="height:200px" id="img1"  src=""></div>
    </th>


   <th scope="col">
         <img id="img2" src=""></div>
  </th>

   <th scope="col">
        <img id="img3" src=""></div>
    </th>
```

And I wanna load one random pic in each  with the following code :

```
var images = ['"image1.jpg"', '"image2.jpg"', '"image3.jpg"', '"image4.jpg"', 'image5.jpg'];
var longitut = images.length;

for(i=0;i<3;i++){


    // Random Image 
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*longitut) ;
    var foto=images[num]; 
    var current='"img'+i+'"';
    alert(foto);

    var objecte =document.getElementById(current);

    objecte.src=foto;
```

The problem is the img src doesn't works, I can't discover the mistake.

Comment: your HTML code is invalid - you don't have opening `<div>` tags

Answer (score 1):

You're not selecting any elements.

Change:

```
var current = '"img' + i + '"';  // If i is 5 it produces '"img5"'
```

to:

```
var current = 'img' + i;  // ==> 'img5'
```

Also, remove the quotes in the images array:

```
'"image1.jpg"' -> 'image1.jpg'
```

Comment: Did you remove the quotes from the images array, too? Also, are the images in the same directory as the JS? @Blackersoul

Answer (score 0):

```
you have to make this changes
<th  scope="col"> 
        <img style="height:200px" id="img1"  src=""></div>
    </th>


   <th scope="col">
         <img id="img2" src=""></div>
  </th>

   <th scope="col">
        <img id="img3" src=""></div>
    </th>

And I wanna load one random pic in each with the following code :

var images = ['"image1.jpg"', '"image2.jpg"', '"image3.jpg"', '"image4.jpg"', 'image5.jpg'];
var longitut = images.length;

for(i=0;i<3;i++){


    // Random Image 
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*longitut) ;
    var foto=images[num]; 
    **var current="image"+i+".jpg";**
    alert(foto);

    var objecte =document.getElementById(current);

    objecte.src=foto;
```

Answer (score 0):

one mistake you have is that you have additional quotes

should look like this:

```
var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg'];
```

and

```
var current='img'+i;
```

The id's of our images are `img1`, `img2` and `img3`. the double quotes in the html code are part of the syntax, not of the ID.

But in your code you add the double quotes to the id you try to search:

```
var current='"img'+i+'"';
```

So you do not find any element.
If you fix this problem, you will still have a problem with your images. that has the same reason you have with the ids. (you try to load the image with the src `"image1.jpg"` but you want to load `image1.jpg`)

Comment: Sorry @t.niese, I don't understant this part:

"otherwise you would search for the element with e.g. the id "img1" but you want to find the one with the id img1. and for the images it is similar. you try to load the image with the src "image1.jpg" but you want to load image1.jpg "
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below html and javascript:

```
<th  scope="col"> 
<img id="img1" style="height:200px" src="" />
</th>
<th scope="col">
<img id="img2" src="" />
</th>
<th scope="col">
<img id="img3" src="" />
 </th>
```

Javascript:

```
var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg'];
var longitut = images.length;
for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
// Random Image 
var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*longitut) ;
var foto=images[num]; 
var current='#img'+i;
$(current).attr("src",foto);
}
```